# C# PowerShell pipeline input flag/property

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

I am creating PowerShell cmdlets in C# by extending the PSCmdlet class.
I need to use the same parameter for pipeline input and normal parameter input. Eg

```
[Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true)]
public Object Connection;
```

Here the Connection parameter can take both pipeline input

```
$connectionValue | Cmdlet-Name
```

and also normal parameter using

```
Cmdlet-Name -Connection $connectionValue
```

Is there a way in C# by which I can find out if the parameter value is pipelined to the cmdlet or provided using -Connection?
In PowerShell this can be done by checking if $input is empty or not. Is there any parameter property that can indicate the input type?

Comment: Why do you need to know this?  I think most users would expect a command to behave the same no matter if they supply input via the pipeline or directly via a parameter argument.

Comment: @Keith $a = @(server1, server2, server3);

Cmdlet-Name -Connection $a -Param1 @("val1", "val2", "val3")
$a | Cmdlet-Name -Parma1 @("val1", "val2", "val3")

For both the above commands, val1 should be used for server1, val2 for server2 and val3 for server3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check by seeing if its set when beginprocessing is called or if it only is set during process record.  Non pipeline properties are set before begin processing is called.